# Can't log out via WooCommerce button, prompts a blank page

Tags: wordpress

I've been trying to sort this out for around 2 days now and I'm at a total loss.

I can't logout of my WordPress site. I created a new test customer and have the default "customer-logout" endpoint set in WooCommerce but clicking the logout button in the My Account page takes me to a blank page.

Anyone have a similar issue or can point me in the right direction?